# BigQuery FARM_FINGERPRINT trailing zeros and not uniformly distributed after mod

Tags: google-bigquery

There is a table with set of data labeled 0 and 1 (~20k records of each label).
FARM_FINGERPRINT is used on id column in order to do train/test split ie. `ABS(MOD(FARM_FINGERPRINT(some_id), 10)) < 8 THEN 'train'` and so on.
This query works fine on a daily basis (with different table each time), but today it resulted in strange results.  Fingerprints of subset with label=1 are normal, but subset where label=0 returns numbers with few trailing zeros ending with a single digit eg. 7026408367856700000 or 7638007046245400007.

What is more, that last digit is **never** bigger than 7, so after MOD 10 all records with label 0 go into train set.
Endings 0-7 are uniformly distributed and in results they are ascending 00000->00007 without any sorting of that column (like numbers were sorted by last five digits)

Ids in the source column look ok, they come from external system and are generated in unrelated process. I checked that it is possible that something like that happened before multiple times.

Comment: Can you share an example of `some_id` that results in those trailing zeros? If you aren't including the `label` column in the hash then it shouldn't affect the output. I'd guess your ids aren't evenly distributed

Comment: It came out that there was an earlier step in the whole process that was applying similar MOD filter to this subset and in this particular case it was executed with <8, when usually multiple digit numbers were used. It didn't handle such edge case where first MOD is single digit.